# How do I make no one able to break blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a Kit PvP world and when my friends play they destroy everything. I don't want to keep rebuilding everytime.

Is there a command with which they can't break any blocks anymore ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Adventure Mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Adventure) (`/gamemode 2`), this way players aren't able to destroy anything except things like vines or tall grass but they are able to do other actions like opening chests or fighting with swords.

The command to set everyone to Adventure mode is: `/gamemode 2 @a`

Comment: This can also be enabled in the server config file

Comment: yeah i think so

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode adventure @a`

Answer (score 2):

But, if you still want to let players place things, that does not work. Another way is to give everyone mining fatigue by using the following:

`/effect player effect seconds amplifier`

For example:

`/effect @a mining_fatigue 100 100`, and have a clock running with command blocks with that continence.

Here's a way to hide the text that says that it did it, Do `/gamerule DoCommandOutput False`

Comment: Every Word Capitalized Is Annoying And Unneccessary.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect @a mining_fatigue 100 100`. Also, the gamerule should be `commandBlockOutput`

Answer (score 0):

If you’re on pc or pe edition you can put the permission on visitor so other players cannot break blocks,or open chests.

Answer (score -2):

You can set each player into adventure mode /gamemode a. This makes them unable to break blocks.

Comment: check your spelling

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode adventure`